# Modern UI for VB NET windows desktop application

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I design my VB.NET application in a modern UI style like the one that is available for WPF  template, for example at [MSDN](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your application *look* like that isn't that difficult, making it *act* like WPF (smooth transitions and animations) is more difficult/impossible

The answer is really to switch to WPF if this is what you want.

Comment: so in other words in order to supporting this kind of modern interface i should use wpf. what about for those users who used to use their common vb net platform for desktop application will this be supported in some time in future? or you think that absolutely will not be supported in vb net such kind of interface

Comment: WinForms will never be developed to look like WPF (IMO). Not unless a vendor brings out some 3rd party components to do it. So if this is what you want WPF is your only option.

Comment: There are 3rd party controls that do stuff like this in winforms but they are costly. IE, DevExpress is what I have used for years. Thier grid is the reason I use them, the rest of the controls are just gravy.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that in Forms is possible but you need to create an massive controls and override a lot of stuff. You might think about switching from Forms to WPF. It might be hard in the beginning but the benefits are worth it.

Comment: i think it many times about switching to WPF but every time i opened it i get confused :)
However i think i must start using wpf at least for a small applications so i can start get familiar with it.

Comment: Same for me :) Was really confused but it's getting better ;)